# Undefined property when accessing to exists object property in javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to get value from object but, when i try to access it property i get error:

`TypeError: this.datas[adragged] is undefined`

I try to debug code, so i add several `console.log`

`console.log(adragged);`
results to: `973`

`console.log(console.log(JSON.stringify(this.datas[adragged])));`
results to:

`{"name":" Наташа ","lname":"","fname":"Наташа","mname":"","id":"973","mother":"900","father":"972","x":0,"y":0,"sex":"F","dbirthd":"","diedate":"","dx":0,"dy":0}`

`console.log(this.datas);` results to:

`Array [ <10 пустых элементов>, ещё 964… ]` and

`973:Object` of array exists and filled with values

`console.log(this.datas[adragged]);`
results to:

`Object { name: " Наташа ", lname: "", fname: "Наташа", mname: "", id: "973", mother: "900", father: "972", x: 0, y: 0, sex: "F", ещё 4… }`

But when i try get `id` from object like this `postData.id = this.datas[adragged].id;` i get error `TypeError: this.datas[adragged] is undefined` on this line.

What i am missing?

Comment: Are you in a closure that lost its `this`-binding? Please post the surrounding code.

Comment: probably a scope error. Please post the surrounding code

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is your data maybe get by an async call?